# command prompt DIR with wildcard returns unexpected results

Tags: command-line-interface

I am running 2003 server (latest service pack). When i type this on the command line:

dir 2010*

or

```
 dir 2010*.*
```

i receive this as the result:

```
    02/01/2011  02:34 PM             2,460 2011-02-01-14-34-23-807.mdn  
    02/02/2011  08:59 AM             3,757 2011-02-02-08-59-32-604.req  
    02/01/2011  09:16 AM               235 2011-02-01-09-16-35-104.dat  
    02/02/2011  05:06 PM               460 2011-02-02-17-06-05-166.log  
    02/01/2011  03:31 PM            66,570 2011-02-01-15-31-27-838.dat  
    02/01/2011  03:16 PM               145 2011-02-01-15-16-51-135.log  
    02/01/2011  08:52 PM         1,608,916 2011-02-01-20-52-57-416.req
                   7 File(s)      1,682,543 bytes  
                   0 Dir(s)  42,891,452,416 bytes free
```

can anyone tell me why? i was expecting to see a list of only files that begin with "2010". there are no such files in the directory, so i wasn't expecting to see anything. i must either misunderstand how DIR handles wildcards or i'm doing something stupid.

Comment: If you have some Linux/Unix knowledge, you could install `cygwin` - isolated application - that offers a true Linux terminal, with all the convenient commands, and `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/235504/directory-search-in-windows-command-prompt-shows-incorrect-output/235657#235657) from user [grawity](https://serverfault.com/users/5799) reveals that the answer lies in the way Windows creates 8.3 filenames and that the `DIR` command looks at ***both*** filenames.

You can see what's happening by using `DIR /X` to show the short filenames.

From that answer:

> When using the NTFS filesystem, 8.3 name creation can be disabled system-wide using:
>
> ```
>     fsutil behavior set disable8dot3
> ```
>
> However, this won't affect existing names.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: the short names of *2011-...* start with *2010* ? (the commands being `DIR 2010*.*`)

Comment: @ring0: They can based on the rule quoted in the answer I linked to. *"if at least 4 files or folders already exist with the same initial 6 characters in their short names, the stripped LFN is instead truncated to the first 2 letters of the basename (or 1 if the basename has only 1 letter), followed by 4 hexadecimal digits derived from an undocumented hash of the filename, followed"*

Answer (score 0):

dir /OD will sort my date  so from there in powershell equivalent would be Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object Date and if you include something Where-Object {!$_.Mode -match "h"} it should do the trick

Comment: that's nice (and i am aware of the various DIR options), but i'm not really asking how to get the results. I'm asking why a DIR 2010* is returning results that i would think i'd only see if doing DIR 2011*. sorry if my question wasn't clear. i edited the question's formatting to improve it.